# Was ist „fickpissig“?

Tags: adjective, compound

Was bedeutet *fickpissig*?

> Kontext (leicht verändert): *Die Reform ist ein fickpissiger Traum für Rechsextreme*.

Comment: Something rude based on _fiicken_ and _pissen_. Not even colloquial language, just new word invention.

Comment: Irgendwass muss es bedeuten, ich gaube nicht, dass das dieselbe Bedeutung wie *Scheißtraum* hat. Also welche denn?

Comment: Nun ja, die beste Zuordnung für solch ein Adjektiv ist vermutlich schon einfach _Scheiss ..._. _Fick_ drückt die Verachtung aus, _pissig_ die Relevanz. Ausserdem ist _piss_ ein Lehnwort aus dem Englischen. Ich glaube nicht, dass die Aussage irgendwas über _"Das ist einfach Scheisse"_ hinaus an Bedeutung und Inhalt hat.

Comment: I think some like "fucking good" or similar. Also, das hat eine umgangsprächliche Bedeutung, darum hast du wahrscheinlich das Downvote erhalten. Vielleicht hat es eine starke negative Bedeutung, aber ich bin fast sicher, daß es starke positive hat (für die sogenannte "Rechtsextreme").

Comment: @c.p. - Bei Fragen wie dieser hilft oft: https://www.mundmische.de, konkret: https://www.mundmische.de/synonyme/fickpissig. https://www.sprachnudel.de hilft in diesem Fall leider nicht, kann aber in vielen anderen Fällen nützlich sein.

Answer (score 2):

First: This adjective is indeed very rude, even vulgar, just because of it's connotation with "ficken" and "pissen".
Some Google search provides actually only two "official" examples, both politically left:

https://gegen-kapital-und-nation.org/vorsicht-kopfnoten/

An article from 1998 (so the word isn't a new invention) about school marks for a pupil's behaviour, which says

> Einen Verbündeten im Kampf gegen die **fickpissige** Idee zur Einführung
>   „moderner Kopfnoten“ werden Schülerinnen und Schüler in Niedersachsen
>   wohl nur in der GEW (Gewerkschaft Erziehung und Wissenschaft) finden.
>   [...] Schule ist so schon schlimm genug. [...] Es muß verhindert
>   werden, daß sie auch noch ein Urteil über die Persönlichkeit von
>   SchülerInnen fällt.

Obviously that adjective doesn't mean anything positive here. It dooms the idea of "Kopfnoten" as something someone can't help but getting enraged on.

Second example is not that clear:

http://www.taz.de/!5570346/

A comment from a newspaper's chief executive on the EU reform plans on copyright laws. Title and abstract:

> **Ein Traum für Facebook und Faschisten**
>   Die Vorlage zur Urheberrechtsreform bringt marginale Verbesserungen. Der Uploadfilter allerdings wird die umfänglichste Vorzensur bislang.

But then:

> Weil Google und Facebook da die Einzigen sind, die den Vorgaben
>   überhaupt genügen können, ist der Artikel 13, der die Uploadfilter
>   vorschreibt, eine langfristige Rückversicherung für ihre
>   marktbeherrschende Stellung.

And finally:

> Dagegen ist das Leistungsschutzrecht ein schlechter Witz, die
>   Uploadfilter aber nur eines: ein **fickpissiger** Fiebertraum für
>   Face­book und Faschisten.

So, as the upload filter ensures the strong position of Facebook, why should it be bad for them?
On the other hand, as the upload filter means that upload content is censored, this is not good for fascists - their propaganda wouldn't reach the people.
So how can it be "fickpissig" for both partys?
Ok, it could be negative for Facebook because they have to spend much effort on implementation and maintenance of such a filter. Also, a negative meaning is implied by the noun "Fiebertraum", what isn't something desirable.
In this context, we would have to consider the title "Ein Traum..." as being ironic.

After all it's more likely that "fickpissig" means something like "beschissen". Anyway, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Oh, du hast das ursprüngliche Zitat gefunden, :) bin mit der Interpretation des infragekommenden Wortes einverstanden (nicht aber mit deiner Iterpretation des taz-Artikels.)